# update TextView From Another SherlockFragment

Tags: android, textview, actionbarsherlock, onclicklistener

I want to update TextView From Another SherlockFragment , I`m using ActionBarSherlock and this my class

**MainActivity Class**

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);
        setContentView(mViewPager);
        final ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1"), Fragment1.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2"), Fragment2.class, null);
    }


}
```

**TabsAdapter Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ActionBar.TabListener , ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo{
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args){
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity fa, ViewPager pager) {
        super(fa.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = fa;
        mActionBar = fa.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args){
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i<mTabs.size(); i++){
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag){
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //Toast.makeText(mContext, "You've deselected a tab", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

}
```

**Fragment1 Class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment{
    TextView t;
    View view;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        t=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        return view;
    }    
}
```

**Fragment2 Class**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class Fragment2 extends SherlockFragment{
    Button b;
    View view;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        b=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(onClick);
        return view;
    }
    public OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }};

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="112dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So what`s the code that`s to change the text of textView1 form Fragment2 Class

```
public OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BroadcastReceiver

In Fragment1's onCreateView:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("updateText");
LocalBroadCastManager localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getSupportActivity());
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String data = bundle.getString("text");
        textView.setText(data);
    }
};
localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

in Fragment2:

```
public OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent updateIntent = new Intent();
        updateIntent.setAction("updateText");
        updateIntent.putExtra("text", "This is the string to show");
        LocalBroadcastManager manager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        manager.sendBroadcast(updateIntent);
    }
};
```

Comment: intent.getBundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
there`s error in intent.getBundle what`s the problem ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Saved my lot of effort. I know something easy thatI am missing. And this is it. Thanks a lot again